# What would be the $.ajax equivalent to this $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I got this method:

```
$.getJSON("http://confidential.com/pcm/datamobile.asmx/ObtenerContactos", {sessionId: 1} , function(data) {
    alert("Success!!! yay");
    peopleList = data;
    jsonIsLoaded();//output your data to console
});
```

I want to convert it to an equivalent one in this format:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

How would that look like?

Comment: Isn't it pretty clear from the documentation? I mean, you even seem to have copied the equivalent Ajax from there. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ What exactly don't you understand? If you don't know how to read it: `$.getJSON` accepts three arguments, named `url`, `data` and `success`. To get the equivalent `$.ajax` call, you take the template shown and replace the values with that arguments/parameters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is already answered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its clear in Official Docs [**jQuery.getJSON()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://confidential.com/pcm/datamobile.asmx/ObtenerContactos",
  data: {sessionId: 1},
  success: function(data) {
        alert("Success!!! yay");
        peopleList = data;
        jsonIsLoaded();//output your data to console
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, more straightforward that I thought it'd be.